# How to create a reusable iconButton mui component the styles the icon btn as well as the icon passed down as props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code, but I'm facing a couple of issues. First, I want to be able to access the theme to style the icon, and I also want to pass the icon from the parent component instead of having it locally. Currently, I don't have access to the theme, and I'm unsure about the correct types for the icon.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import IconButton, { IconButtonProps } from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import LocalBarIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LocalBar';

const StyledIcon = {
  marginTop: 2.5,
  marginBottom: 2.5,
  marginRight: 2.5,
  marginLeft: 2.5,
  borderRadius: 50,
  padding: 3,
  fontSize: 30,
  cursor: 'pointer',
  //   color: theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 800 : 50],
  //   backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 50 : 600],
  //   '&:hover': {
  //     color: theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 50 : 800],
  //     background: theme.palette.grey[theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 800 : 50],
  //   },
};

const StyledIconButton = styled(IconButton)({
  padding: 0,
  background: 'transparent',
  '&:hover': {
    background: 'transparent',
  },
  '&.Mui-disabled': {
    '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
      color: 'inherit',
    },
  },
});

interface IconButtonComponentProps extends IconButtonProps {
  tooltip: string;
  icon: React.ReactNode;
  disabled: boolean;
  onClickFn: () => void;
}

const IconButtonComponent: FC<IconButtonComponentProps> = ({ tooltip, icon, disabled, onClickFn }) => {
  return (
    <Tooltip title={tooltip}>
      <StyledIconButton disableRipple disableFocusRipple disabled={disabled} onClick={onClickFn}>
        <LocalBarIcon sx={StyledIcon} />
      </StyledIconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

export default IconButtonComponent;
```